# How to disable the cache tables

Tags: 7, caching

I make a newspaper website from long time using drupal 7 and now its database is very large.
Most of the time, the database server is down because of that. The tables that are more problematic are cache, cache_*, and watchdog.

Is there any way to avoid those tables are used?
Today I tried deleting the rows in those tables with SQL, but it took more than 3 hours.

Comment: Drupal itself needs the block and some other features to be cached, If your table is big try disable caching in `admin > config > performance`

Comment: Do you have [cron](http://drupal.org/cron) running?  If not, that could be the root cause of those tabling getting too big.  Part of the normal cron tasks is to delete expired cache entries and to prune the watchdog table.

Comment: I have make it 3 hours ,it was 1 week

Comment: If your site is large and busy, I think I would recommend running it more often, seeing as if it is left too long, it can take a very long time to run, and reach max_execution_time or max memory limit. Additionally you could disable the database logging module (dblog I think) and instead use syslog, both are core modules, syslog does not log to the database. Syslog guide: https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog Just remember to rotate, gzip, and/or delete the older log files.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to disable the cache; it will make all slower.
The [DB Maintenance](http://drupal.org/project/db_maintenance) module will do cleanup tasks for you.

> DB maintenance optimizes administrator-selected tables in the database during regular cron.php executions. For MyISAM tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE repairs a table if it has deleted or split rows, sorts table indexes, and updates table statistics. For BDB and InnoDB, OPTIMIZE rebuilds the table. Note, MySQL locks tables during the time OPTIMIZE TABLE is running.

Answer (score 1):

you can definitely switch off the "Database Logging" (dblog) module from core, that will take care of the **watchdog** table. It might be good to check whats there, though - could be you have some missing files and get an entry for each request ...

For caching, you can use other systems, such as [APC](http://drupal.org/project/apc), [memcache](http://drupal.org/project/memcache), [file system](http://drupal.org/project/filecache).

Comment: do you think that file cache is good it is not beta version

Comment: i only used cacherouter on d6, but would believe that this good enough :). if you dont use the RAM disk though, it is only useful for some stuff - probably pages.